# How to change src dynamically from text file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have to change the src of an audio tag dynamically depends of a text file that I've got. I'm using HTML + PHP + MySQL. No JS, jQuery, or other things yet (because I don't know).
The text file is generated with a Python script, so i have to read the content and put it in the src path.

Example:

Content of file.txt: 123456789
Final HTML code that i need:

```html
<source src="../file_123456789.wav" type="audio/wav">
```

How can I read a file and use it as a string/variable to put in HTML? I'm thinking open the file with PHP and do an 'echo $content;' inside the src path but I think that there are better ways to do that.

Regards,

Comment: `No JS, jQuery,` - you'll need JS to read the file (using some sort of AJAX, like XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: It's the only possible way? I'm trying to avoid using JS because some browsers dont support it totally or the JS may be disabled. Also, I don't know JS (yet).

Comment: can you do it in PHP then

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use js, then just do it in php like you said.

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
?>

<source src="../file_<?php echo $file;?>.wav" type="audio/wav">
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for! It work very well.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you use JS/JQuery and you can find answer to this question. However, if you don't want to use JS/JQuery reading file and echoing it is the only method. 
If you are willing to use JQuery this will work. Find a Jquery CDN and link it in your HTML. Then:

```
<script>
$.get("file.txt", function(result){
   var scr = document.createElement('source');
   scr.type = 'audio/wav';
   scr.src = '../file_' + result + '.wav';
   document.body.appendChild(scr);
   });
 </script>
```